# Setting manual thermal voltage for a diode in LTSPICE

Tags: diodes, solar-cell, simulation, spice, ltspice

I want to simulate some series and parallel connected solar cells with the same reference temperature but different operation temperature for each cell. To do so, I need to configure the thermal voltage of the diodes which I use in my circuit.

The problem is that it is not possible to change the operating temperature (.Temp) for each element of the circuit. Therefore, I want to calculate the diode properties manually. For the diode model, I do not know how can I specify the thermal voltage manually and I need your help.

[image]

`Vt=kT/q` is the thermal voltage that I want to configure it to a specific value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the temperature for each component individually using the following approach:

After placing your component and selecting the correct model for it, do a CTRL+Rightclick on the component. In the newly opened window, search for the "SpiceLine" field and enter `temp=500` (or whatever value).

Now your diode will have that temperature where the rest of your circuit does not.

Example:

[image: how to enter the temperature on one component]

In the LT-Spice netlist the line for the diode is displayed like this:

```
D2 N002 0 1N914 temp=500
```

With following result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! It works perfectly correct!
One more question: how can I add `temp=500` to diode if I want to use it as netlist (I do not use schematic). I tried to export the schematic as a netlist but it just gave me no information!
  P.S. Since I have less than 15 reputations, I cannot vote for you but please accept my thanks in comment.

Comment: @HAMED I've included the netlist line for the diode with the changed temperature. I got this via: "View" -> "SPICE Netlist". I haven't tried if it works if you input the netlist by hand, but I guess it will.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was using export netlist which gave me incorrect data. Now it works and I know what to do. Many thanks again